# Driver for Fuji Xerox DocuPrint P115 b?

Tags: drivers, printing, xerox

I'm having difficulty finding a driver to allow me to print with this printer. I've tried installing the built-in drivers for Fuji Xerox printers with similar-sounding model names but nothing comes out at the printer end with those.

According to the manual that came with the printer, there's meant to be both an LPR and CUPS driver available for Linux.

Comment: A while ago I got a support phone call back from Fuji Xerox who insisted that because it's a low-end printer it relies on the Windows GDI system and only supports Windows. But I know that's wrong because they distribute a Macintosh CUPS driver for it (runs print jobs through their proprietary Mac binaries, so doesn't work with Linux directly), not to mention that the manual mentions a Linux driver.